# ConcurrentModificationException drools persistence Spring

Tags: java, spring, drools

I need to use drools persistence in Spring application, but I stacked with an issue of parallel accessing several kie sessions from different threads.

Actually, the behaviour is unexpected, sometimes I have got **ConcurrentModificationException**, sometimes **NullPointerException**. I wrote a little project for experiments: https://github.com/sibmaks/drools_spring_persistance.

Test: **singleSessionWritesTest** always works fine, because I work with one kie-session in sequential mode, but **multipleWritesTest** falls with errors.

Framework versions:

Drools: 7.43.1.Final

Spring: 1.5.8.RELEASE

Can anybody hint me where I made a mistake or what I have to read for fix the issue?

P.S. Code snippets

Beans configs:

```java
//...

@Configuration
public class DroolsConfig {

//...

   @Bean
   @Qualifier("droolsEnvironment")
   public Environment droolsEnvironment(
           @Qualifier("droolsDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
           //@Qualifier("drools-entityManagerFactory")
           //        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean droolsEntityManagerFactory,
           KieServices kieServices) {
       LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean droolsEntityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
       droolsEntityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
       droolsEntityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName("drools.cookbook.persistence.jpa");
       droolsEntityManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

       JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(droolsEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
       jpaTransactionManager.setNestedTransactionAllowed(false);
       jpaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet();

       TransactionManager transactionManager = new KieSpringTransactionManager(jpaTransactionManager);

       Environment environment = kieServices.newEnvironment();
       environment.set(EnvironmentName.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY, droolsEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
       environment.set(EnvironmentName.PERSISTENCE_CONTEXT_MANAGER, new KieSpringJpaManager(environment));
       environment.set(EnvironmentName.TRANSACTION_MANAGER, transactionManager);
       environment.set(EnvironmentName.GLOBALS, new MapGlobalResolver());
       return environment;
   }

/...
}
```

Get or load kie session code:

```java
    protected KieSessionContainer getOrCreate(String externalId) {
        if (!kieSessionMap.containsKey(externalId)) {
            creationLock.lock();
            try {
                if (!kieSessionMap.containsKey(externalId)) {
                    ClientKieSession clientKieSession = clientKieSessionRepository.findFirstByClientId(externalId);
                    KieSession kieSession;
                    if (clientKieSession == null) {
                        log.info("**** Create session for client: {}", externalId);
                        kieSession = droolsService.createSession(externalId);
                    } else {
                        log.info("**** Restore session for client: {}", externalId);
                        try {
                            kieSession = droolsService.loadSession(clientKieSession.getSessionIdentifier());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            log.error("**** Restore session for error, create new session", e);
                            clientKieSessionRepository.delete(clientKieSession);
                            return droolsService.getOrCreate(externalId);
                        }
                    }
                    kieSession.addEventListener(new EventHandler());
                    kieSessionMap.put(externalId, new KieSessionContainer(kieSession, new ReentrantLock()));
                }
            } finally {
                creationLock.unlock();
            }
        }
        return kieSessionMap.get(externalId);
    }

    @Transactional
    protected KieSession createSession(String externalId) {
        KieSession kieSession = kieStoreServices.newKieSession(kieBase, kieSessionConfiguration, environment);
        ClientKieSession clientKieSession = new ClientKieSession();
        clientKieSession.setSessionIdentifier(kieSession.getIdentifier());
        clientKieSession.setClientId(externalId);
        clientKieSession.setCreated(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));
        clientKieSessionRepository.save(clientKieSession);
        return kieSession;
    }

    @Transactional
    protected KieSession loadSession(long identifier) {
        return kieStoreServices.loadKieSession(identifier, kieBase, kieSessionConfiguration, environment);
    }
```

Fact insert code (produce exceptions)

```java
    @Transactional
    protected void processFacts(KieSession kieSession, Object ... facts) {
        for(Object fact : facts) {
            kieSession.execute(CommandFactory.newInsert(fact));
        }
        kieSession.fireAllRules();
    }
```

Test code:

```java
        Random random = new Random();
        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);
        List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            ids.add(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        AtomicInteger finished = new AtomicInteger();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        AtomicBoolean exception = new AtomicBoolean();
        for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
            executor.execute(() -> {
                if(exception.get()) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    droolsService.processFacts(ids.get(random.nextInt(ids.size())), new LongFact(counter.incrementAndGet()));
                    finished.incrementAndGet();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                    exception.set(true);
                }
            });
        }
        while (finished.get() != COUNT && !exception.get()) {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("{} execution time. {} op per second", (end - time), (0.0 + end - time) / COUNT);

        int result = 0;
        int resultQ = 0;
        for(String id : ids) {
            result += droolsService.sessionDump(id).stream().filter(it -> it instanceof LongFact).count();
            resultQ += droolsService.processQuery(id, "getLongs").size();
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(COUNT, result);
        Assert.assertEquals(COUNT, resultQ);
```

Exceptions example:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1042) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:580) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.flush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.drools.persistence.TriggerUpdateTransactionSynchronization.beforeCompletion(TriggerUpdateTransactionSynchronization.java:76) ~[drools-persistence-jpa-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.kie.spring.persistence.SpringTransactionSynchronizationAdapter.beforeCompletion(SpringTransactionSynchronizationAdapter.java:54) ~[kie-spring-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:106) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:945) [spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:745) [spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) [spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.kie.spring.persistence.KieSpringTransactionManager.commit(KieSpringTransactionManager.java:70) [kie-spring-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.PersistableRunner$TransactionInterceptor.execute(PersistableRunner.java:608) [drools-persistence-jpa-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.PersistableRunner$TransactionInterceptor.execute(PersistableRunner.java:565) [drools-persistence-jpa-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.PersistableRunner.execute(PersistableRunner.java:400) [drools-persistence-jpa-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.PersistableRunner.execute(PersistableRunner.java:68) [drools-persistence-jpa-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.runtime.InternalLocalRunner.execute(InternalLocalRunner.java:37) [drools-core-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.runtime.InternalLocalRunner.execute(InternalLocalRunner.java:41) [drools-core-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.impl.CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.execute(CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.java:537) [drools-core-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.example.drools_persistance_spring.service.DroolsService.processFacts(DroolsService.java:74) [main/:na]
    at org.example.drools_persistance_spring.service.DroolsService.processFacts(DroolsService.java:64) [main/:na]
    at org.example.drools_persistance_spring.service.DroolsServiceTest.lambda$multipleWritesTest$2(DroolsServiceTest.java:84) [test/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
```

Another exception (after restart test)

```
javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: -1; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapStaleStateException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1729) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1634) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1303) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.flush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.drools.persistence.TriggerUpdateTransactionSynchronization.beforeCompletion(TriggerUpdateTransactionSynchronization.java:76) ~[drools-persistence-jpa-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.kie.spring.persistence.SpringTransactionSynchronizationAdapter.beforeCompletion(SpringTransactionSynchronizationAdapter.java:54) ~[kie-spring-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:106) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:945) [spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:745) [spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) [spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.kie.spring.persistence.KieSpringTransactionManager.commit(KieSpringTransactionManager.java:70) [kie-spring-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.PersistableRunner$TransactionInterceptor.execute(PersistableRunner.java:608) [drools-persistence-jpa-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.PersistableRunner$TransactionInterceptor.execute(PersistableRunner.java:565) [drools-persistence-jpa-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.PersistableRunner.execute(PersistableRunner.java:400) [drools-persistence-jpa-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.PersistableRunner.execute(PersistableRunner.java:68) [drools-persistence-jpa-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.runtime.InternalLocalRunner.execute(InternalLocalRunner.java:37) [drools-core-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.runtime.InternalLocalRunner.execute(InternalLocalRunner.java:41) [drools-core-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.drools.core.command.impl.CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.execute(CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.java:537) [drools-core-7.43.1.Final.jar:7.43.1.Final]
    at org.example.drools_persistance_spring.service.DroolsService.processFacts(DroolsService.java:74) [main/:na]
    at org.example.drools_persistance_spring.service.DroolsService.processFacts(DroolsService.java:64) [main/:na]
    at org.example.drools_persistance_spring.service.DroolsServiceTest.lambda$multipleWritesTest$2(DroolsServiceTest.java:84) [test/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: -1; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3134) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3013) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3393) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question itself.

Comment: change the foreach loop (for(Object fact : facts)) to fori loop. it might be the problem.

Comment: @MoRtEzATM not helped. And I thought that in this case, I have got an error for the test with one kie session.